# How to extract a single file from a tar which itself is also inside a tar?

Tags: archive, tar

How can we extract a file ( lets call it file c.txt ) from a tar ( B.tar ) which itself is inside a tar (A.tar). Without extracting any of the parent tar files completely.

Structure is

```
A.tar -> B.tar -> c.txt

Here A.tar is 300GB  
B.tar is 200GB  
c.txt is only 2GB
```

There is this question which I found similar
[How to extract a tar file inside a tar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897060/how-to-extract-a-tar-file-inside-a-tar-file)

In this the output may look similar but here the 2nd file (B.tar) will be extracted in its entirety then c.txt will be extracted from it, which will take lots of time. whereas what I want is to only extract c.txt

Comment: In the link, `B.tar` is extracted only to stdout, not in a file, you can't do best than extract `B.tar` first to extract something in it. Just add the corresponding argument to the second command to extract the single file you need.

Comment: but extracting it to stdout will take same amount of time, as B.tar is 200GB